# Android User Interface - Are tabs at the bottom the best approach?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am creating an app that provides users information about a building that the app is being designed for.  For example it will tell the user the location of the building, hotels/restaurants/cafes nearby and some other useful information.

I will be creating seperate activities to carry this out, so an activity to tell user the location and maybe contain a map, an activity listing hotels and an activity listing nearby cafes etc.

My problem is that I am not sure how to design the interface for this.  I was thinking of having tabs at the botton of the screen where each tab opens the corresponding activity.  Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is really a UX (user experience) decision, not a coder decision. You are probably asking this question on a wrong site.

I recommend you look around how other apps have solved a similar problem, to get ideas what is possible. Then pick a solution that you like best.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask that at [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)
Personally I think Tabs are a quite intuitive way to let the user choose between dedicated views/activities - especially if they are labelled with distinct icons

Answer (score 0):

Tabs is always a clean solution.

Maybe something like a dashboard would also be nice. (Pattern 3 in my link)

This link covers some things that may be useful in further development.

[Android Dev UI Development](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Answer (score 0):

Right now i can think of some other solutions

- Use a gesture to swap to another activity
- Use a pair of arrow buttons at the bottom

But your solution seems nicer